# Insert and fill rows of missing dates with NA in List R

Tags: r, datetime, merge, time-series, missing-data

Currently I have multiple dataframes in a list with the following format:

```
             datetime precip code
1 2015-04-15 00:00:00     NA    M
2 2015-04-15 01:00:00     NA    M
3 2015-04-15 02:00:00     NA    M
4 2015-04-15 03:00:00     NA    M
5 2015-04-15 04:00:00     NA    M
6 2015-04-15 05:00:00     NA    M
```

Each dataframe has a different start and end date but I will like each dataframe to start from `2015-04-01 0:00:00` to `2015-11-30 23:59:59`. I would like to generate rows for the missing dates in `datetime` in each dataframe and fill the `precip`column with `NA`so that I have a continuous time series with `nrow=5856`in each dataframe.

Ignore the `code` column. If values exist for `precip`, do not alter them, just fill the additional `datetime` `rows` with `NAs`

My attempt so far yields an error:

```
library(dplyr)
dates <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt("2015-04-01 0:00:00"), as.POSIXlt("2015-11-30 23:59:59"), by="hour",tz="GMT")
ts <- format.POSIXct(dates,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
df <- data.frame(datetime=ts)
dat=mylist
final_list <- lapply(dat, function(x) full_join(df,dat$precip))

Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

[link to sample file in case it is needed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lya8tiwxkax4c0/L112FN0M.262.csv?dl=0)

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You trying to use full_join to join a data.frame with a vector, but the function was designed to join 2 data.frames.

Comment: @vitor         any better way to resolve my posted problem is most welcome.

Comment: make the elements of your list into `data.frames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vitor pointed out above, you can only join two data.frames, not a data.frame and a vector. `dplyr` also plays nice with `POSIXct`, but not `POSIXlt` (Hadley has a preference), so if you store your data as actual time, it will be easier to join usefully.

Further, within `lapply`, you need to use the variable of the function you create (`x` here), or you'll just be repeating the same thing. Don't subset the data.frames, either, if you want to join them; you need a column in each with the same name and data type.

All together, you need something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, tz = "GMT")
df <- tbl_df(df)    # not necessary, but prints nicely

list_df <- list(df, df)    # fake list of data.frames
# make a data.frame of sequence to join on
seq_df <- data_frame(datetime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 0:00:00", tz = 'GMT'), 
                                           as.POSIXct("2015-11-30 23:59:59", tz = 'GMT'), 
                                           by="hour",tz="GMT"))

lapply(list_df, function(x){full_join(x, seq_df)})
# Joining by: "datetime"
# Joining by: "datetime"
# [[1]]
# Source: local data frame [5,857 x 3]
# 
#               datetime precip   code
#                 (POSI)  (lgl) (fctr)
# 1  2015-04-15 00:00:00     NA      M
# 2  2015-04-15 01:00:00     NA      M
# 3  2015-04-15 02:00:00     NA      M
# 4  2015-04-15 03:00:00     NA      M
# 5  2015-04-15 04:00:00     NA      M
# 6  2015-04-15 05:00:00     NA      M
# 7  2015-04-01 04:00:00     NA     NA
# 8  2015-04-01 05:00:00     NA     NA
# 9  2015-04-01 06:00:00     NA     NA
# 10 2015-04-01 07:00:00     NA     NA
# ..                 ...    ...    ...
# 
# [[2]]
# Source: local data frame [5,857 x 3]
# 
#               datetime precip   code
#                 (POSI)  (lgl) (fctr)
# 1  2015-04-15 00:00:00     NA      M
# 2  2015-04-15 01:00:00     NA      M
# 3  2015-04-15 02:00:00     NA      M
# 4  2015-04-15 03:00:00     NA      M
# 5  2015-04-15 04:00:00     NA      M
# 6  2015-04-15 05:00:00     NA      M
# 7  2015-04-01 04:00:00     NA     NA
# 8  2015-04-01 05:00:00     NA     NA
# 9  2015-04-01 06:00:00     NA     NA
# 10 2015-04-01 07:00:00     NA     NA
# ..                 ...    ...    ...
```

#### Data:

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1429056000, 1429059600, 1429063200, 1429066800, 
    1429070400, 1429074000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), precip = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "M", 
    class = "factor")), .Names = c("datetime", "precip", "code"), row.names = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks for providing an answer. I tried to apply your code but it gave me different results: `tail(finalstations[[1]])
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

             datetime precip   code
               (time)  (dbl) (fctr)
1 2015-12-01 00:00:00     NA     NA
2 2015-12-01 01:00:00     NA     NA
3 2015-12-01 02:00:00     NA     NA
4 2015-12-01 03:00:00     NA     NA
5 2015-12-01 04:00:00     NA     NA
6 2015-12-01 05:00:00     NA     NA`. The first date in each df should be `2015-04-01 0:00:00` and the last 2015-11-30 23:00:00 as in `seq_df`.

Comment: Fixed. `as.POSIXct` was assuming the local time zone in making `seq_df`.

Comment: your solution is almost right if not of the following: `datetime` in the final output (`dff`) is not continuous. E.g in `df`, `datetime` starts on `2015-04-15 00:00:00`. In `dff` I want datetime to be 1) continuous as in `seq_df`. Each dataframe in `dff` should have all dates in `seq_df`. 2) Please use this within a list object: `df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, tz = "GMT")`. I have provided a sample file in the link above. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The data _is_ continuous (in the sense you're using it), it's just not sorted, so the rows merged from `df` are still listed up top. You can just switch `x` and `seq_df` in the join, if you like, or actually sort with `arrange` if order matters: `lapply(list_df, function(x){full_join(x, seq_df) %>% arrange(datetime)})`.

Comment: great solution. Thanks.

Comment: great solution. Thanks. Previously, I asked how to convert `df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, tz = "GMT")` within a `list object`. I tried `df=list(df,df)`; `lappy(df, function (x) {as.POSIXct([df$datetime,] tz = "GMT")})` but failed. Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: You still aren't putting the variable into your `lapply` functions. `lapply(df, function(x){x$datetime <- as.POSIXct(x$datetime, tz = "GMT"); x})` is one option where you can see what's going on.